# PHP Foreach display with same value

Tags: php, mysql

How to display data group by `$vendorid`, When I order 5 products from different vendors.

Ex : Random added products to cart.

```
| $vendorid | $product_name |
-----------------------------
|     1     |    TEST31     |
|     4     |    TEST21     |
|     3     |    TEST20     |
|     3     |    TEST17     |
|     4     |    TEST11     |
```

But I want to display like this :

```
| $vendorid | $product_name |
-----------------------------
|     1     |    TEST31     |
|     3     |    TEST20     |
|     3     |    TEST17     |
|     4     |    TEST21     |
|     4     |    TEST11     |
```

Code :

```
foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product){

    $product_name = $product["p_name"];
    $vendorid = $product["p_member_id"];        
    $cart_box = "<li>$vendorid $product_name</li>";
}
echo $cart_box;
```

This gives me an output in the same result that I've added to cart like this :

```
| $vendorid | $product_name |
-----------------------------
|     1     |    TEST31     |
|     4     |    TEST21     |
|     3     |    TEST20     |
|     3     |    TEST17     |
|     4     |    TEST11     |
```

Comment: Apply sort function.

Comment: assuming _SESSION["products"] comes from a datasource, just use an order by ( at the source )

Comment: What they are saying is that you need to use ORDER BY in the mysql_query string at the end. add this to the end of the string `ORDER BY  p_member_id;`

Comment: Add `ODER BY p_member_id ASC` at last....

Comment: I somehow doubt that ORDER BY is the solution here. Given that _SESSION is used, it's more likely that somehwere code like `$_SESSION['products'][] = $newitem;` is executed (without hitting the database at this stage).

Comment: if you could post more of the code it would give a clearer picture of the problem.

Comment: Thank you guys, But  `ORDER BY p_member_id;` it doesn't work.
This is my query `"SELECT p_name, p_price, p_member_id FROM fm_product WHERE p_id=? order by p_member_id asc LIMIT 1"` I've try to added  `ORDER BY p_member_id;` it still displayed old result.

Comment: I seriously doubt that you assign the result of `SELECT .... ORDER BY ...` directly to `$_SESSION['products']`, right? You append items to that array whenever the user chooses an item, and again if the user chooses another product, and another and so on, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
// sample data
$_SESSION["products"] = [];
$_SESSION["products"][] = ['vendorid'=>1, 'product_name'=>'TEST31' ];
$_SESSION["products"][] = ['vendorid'=>4, 'product_name'=>'TEST21' ];
$_SESSION["products"][] = ['vendorid'=>3, 'product_name'=>'TEST20' ];
$_SESSION["products"][] = ['vendorid'=>3, 'product_name'=>'TEST17' ];
$_SESSION["products"][] = ['vendorid'=>4, 'product_name'=>'TEST11' ];

// actual code
usort($_SESSION["products"], function($a, $b) {
    return $a['vendorid'] - $b['vendorid'];
});

foreach( $_SESSION["products"] as $product ) {
    echo '<li>',
        htmlspecialchars($product['vendorid']), ' ', htmlspecialchars($product['product_name']),
    "</li>\r\n";
}
```

prints

```
<li>1 TEST31</li>
<li>3 TEST17</li>
<li>3 TEST20</li>
<li>4 TEST11</li>
<li>4 TEST21</li>
```

It doesn't really matter where and when you sort the `$_SESSION["products"]` array.
But if you do it every time a new item is appended you don't have to do it every time you display the cart and if (and when) php gets some "sorted-insert-into-array" functon you can replace the code by that and save some computation time....

see also: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try your code on the next Monday.

Comment: Hi, I've try your code and it's displayed this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected  '['` on first line.

Comment: Then you are using php < 5.4 and have to use `array()` instead of `[ ]` for array literals, see https://3v4l.org/V3quT and http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Answer (score 1):

try the below function it will work

```
function aasort (&$array, $key) {
$sorter=array();
$ret=array();
reset($array);
foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
    $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
}
asort($sorter);
foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
    $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
}
$array=$ret;
```

}

aasort($_SESSION["products"],"p_member_id");

Comment: Thank you so much, But I'll try your code on the next Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY` in query to ascending in the query.

For example:

```
ORDER BY ID ASC;
```

Comment: what is the issue? reply me with your query

Comment: Problem solved, But thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: it's my pleasure. i think you are new in database designing! best of luck